# Why can I see Wordpress content with "View Source" if the content is loaded from a server?

Tags: wordpress

I know that using "View Source" on a webpage only gives you the original page source from when the page was loaded. Anything added to the page by Javascript or an Ajax call doesn't appear in the source code. I understand that.

However, Wordpress seems to be different. When I view the source code of a Wordpress page, everything is there – the meta data, the page content, etc. Yet these things are loaded from a database. So how is it possible for the page content, etc. to be in the source code if they're loaded dynamically from a database?

Comment: This question is not really appropriate for Stack Overflow as information regarding PHP/HTML and how a browser renders code is easily found everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found the answer.

If I do an ajax request using javascript, then the page source will only shows the javascript and not what is loaded from the server.

But if I put the request to the server directly in php tags instead of doing an ajax request:

```
<body>
<?php
    include('db_connection_details.php');
    $query = "SELECT ID FROM Database_name ORDER BY ID ASC";
    $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        echo $row['ID'] . " ";
    }
?>
</body>
```

then the page source only shows the result from the server.

Answer (score 0):

Content ca be loaded from a database or written within the page html itself. When a browser reads a web page, it is after the database provided the content to the page, same thing if the page had the content written in the page itself. Wordpress doesn't do anything unusal. Wordpress is not adding your content via javascript neither ajax.

I really did answer this.

Answer (score 0):

Because PHP code rendered on the server.so if you are adding shortcodes or anything in php file it will get rendered on the server before transferred into the browser so at the end browser got rendered version which will get all rendered content.

While in terms of CSR application(React js)typically all code rendered on the browser itself so now rendering from the server, coz browser can handle that but not in terms of PHP, PHP needs a server.

Comment: I just did a test. I put the word "foobar" in a file called test.php and then put <?php include "test.php"; ?> in another php file. Then I viewed the page source of the second file and I did indeed only see "foobar". So you are right. But is this really how Wordpress pages are rendered? Wordpress stores blog posts in a database, so wouldn't it would have to run an ajax call to get the blog post?

Comment: Yes this is how WordPress rendered its page, WordPress fetches data from MySQL select query on the server through its function (WP_QUERY) so it is already rendered, but if you add load more post functionality on your blogs on frontend then it will not be rendered in view source coz browser didn't refreshed its DOM.